# Tukey HSD pvalues in R

Tags: r, anova, lm, tukey-hsd-test

I have the following subset of dataset which I am using to create a boxplot (using ggplot) between study and FPKM:

```
head(total)

                study            gene_id              disease         id FPKM freq
1 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1090407 0.68 7859
2 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1310542 0.32 7859
3 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1377423 2.29 7859
4 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1413501 0.19 7859
5 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1376939 1.22 7859
6 GTEx Normals (7859) ENSG00000149294.16 Adipose Tissue (515) SRR1332969 0.64 7859
```

[image]

I calculate the difference between the boxes using:

```
anovaRes <- aov(lm(total$FPKM~total$study))
pvals <- TukeyHSD(anovaRes)[[1]]
pvals
                                        diff lwr upr   p adj
TARGET NBL (151)-GTEx Normals (7859)     118 110 125 2.4e-11
NBL PDX (15)-GTEx Normals (7859)          98  75 121 2.4e-11
NBL Cell Lines (40)-GTEx Normals (7859)   46  32  60 2.4e-11
NBL PDX (15)-TARGET NBL (151)            -20 -44   4 1.4e-01
NBL Cell Lines (40)-TARGET NBL (151)     -71 -87 -56 2.4e-11
NBL Cell Lines (40)-NBL PDX (15)         -51 -78 -25 4.8e-06
```

I am confused that most of the pvalues are identical - Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It likely depends on the size of your data set. If you data set is really large (as you appropriately only provided a sample), then it wouldn't surprise me that you had a lot of p-values that are all extremely small and similar.